# Make divs on the top of the other div

Tags: html, css

My goal is to display info on those chart div like this:

[image]

I was able to [show](https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/241d14a27427dd89133e1b07919ee9b6) it on div but the thing is those were not responsive in nature. So I have started from scratch and writing the code again to solve that issue.

So in my new code, When I uncomment those divs under `class kpi-box`:

This is **what I get:**
[image]

My graph gets shifted to right side.

This is **what it should look like**:

[image]

**Code snippet:**

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="chart-holder">
      <div id="kpi-confirmed" class="kpi-box">
              <div class="label">Death</div> //<----------------- from here
              <div class="value">123</div>
              <div class="diff">12345</div>
              <div class="description"></div>
              <div id="daily_dcsd"></div>
              <div class="chart-caption">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Daily new cases</div>        
      </div>
      <div id="test2" class="kpi-box">
<!--               <div class="label">Death</div>
              <div class="value">123</div>
              <div class="diff">12345</div>
              <div class="description"></div>
              <div id="daily_dcsd"></div>
              <div class="chart-caption">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Daily new cases</div>  -->
              <!-- <br>        -->
      </div>
```

**Code and demo:**

**Line no. 1-124:**

https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/7ff7bc1ea3e100d9a8d92aa6bcec3fb6

I know I need to use `position absolute` and `position relative` but I ain't able to do it. Can someone help me in this?

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you wanted as a solution. I have checked the blockbuilder snippet. Do you want them to be expanded to the whole width? or something else

Comment: I want them to overlay on the chart div.

Comment: Remember that absolute position is referenced by the previous explicitly declared relative positioned element.

Answer (score 2):

As the height of the child css selector is limiting the height of the box you are not able to adjust the all contents to the box. Remove the height for the child class or reduce the height of the svg.

```css
.child {
  flex: 1 10 20%;
  /* explanation below */
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  /*height: 12.5vw;*/
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Where to make the changes. Not a web developer so it's kinda new to me. Although I have fixed the issue. The issue was with the `diff` class div which show values in circular bracket. I append them to `label class` in script part by using span in place of div. Which fixes my issue .

Comment: If you mean to change the `line 27`:    `#kpi-confirmed,#test2, #test3, #test4 {` Then I am get the other issue.

Answer (score 1):

First wrap all your extra information in a `<div>` then make it `absolute`.

```
<div style="position: absolute;top: 10px;left: 10px;">
      <div class="value">123</div>
      <div class="diff">12345</div>
      <div class="description"></div>
      <div class="label">Death</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: doesn't work. My all charts are getting stacked together.

Answer (score 1):

Gotten from your code in

https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/7ff7bc1ea3e100d9a8d92aa6bcec3fb6

````
     flex:20px 1 1 1;
     display:flex;
     flex-direction:row;
     min-height:0;
     position: absolute;
     flex-wrap:nowrap;}```

Edit depending on the size it will give the charts when displayed ``flex:30px 1 1 1;``
````

Comment: which line to change?

Comment: It didn't help. Did you try and check that whether it works?